# MongoDB and NoRM - Querying collection against a list of parameters

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, norm

I need to query a collection based on a list of parameters. 
For example my model is:

```
public class Product
{
    string id{get;set;}
    string title{get;set;}
    List<string> tags{get;set;}
    DateTime createDate{get;set;}
    DbReference<User> owner{get;set;}
}

public class User
{
    string id{get;set;}
    ...other properties...
}
```

I need to query for all products owned by specified users and sorted by creationDate.

For example:

```
GetProducts(List<string> ownerIDs)
{
    //query
}
```

I need to do it in one query if possible not inside foreach. I can change my model if needed

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for the $in identifier. You could query products like so:

```
db.product.find({owner.$id: {$in: [ownerId1, ownerId2, ownerId3] }}).sort({createDate:1});
```

Just replace that javascript array [ownerId1, ...] with your own array of owners.

As a note: I would guess this query is not very efficient. I haven't had much luck with DBRefs in MongoDB, which essentially adds relations to a non-relational database. I would suggest simply storing the ownerID directly in the product object and querying based on that.

Comment: Regarding DbRef it's not a must, I actually have both ref and id. However can you think of a way of doing the suggested in linq expression, which I use. I use NoRM as C# driver

Comment: With Linq... that is a good question. My first impression would be to use the Contains() function and pass it an array, but I am not sure it takes anything but a string. I will look into it.

Comment: This doesn't have a linq example, but does have a standard example to start you out: http://codefather.pl/post/1369797147/nosql-no-problem-norm-and-mongodb-tutorial
Scroll down to the $in part.

Comment: Thanks Clint, I will check this one

Answer (score 1):

The solution using LINQ is making an array of user IDs and then do .Contains on them like that:

```
List<string> users = new List<string>();
foreach (User item in ProductUsers)
    users .Add(item.id);

return MongoSession.Select<Product>(p => users .Contains(p.owner.id))
                    .OrderByDescending(p => p.createDate)
                    .ToList();
```